# How to remove unwanted short time signal Simulink

Tags: matlab, signals, simulink, modeling

I want to remove a unwanted signal that occurs for 0.02sec. For example...i have a continuous signal with value 1. For a reason i become in some cases a signal with any value (+ or -) for max 0.02sec. After that I become again the value 1. Is it possible to remove this unwanted signal?

I will be very thankful for any help!

With best regards

Comment: Your question is very unclear.  The simplest thing to do is to use a constant block with a value of 1, but I suspect that doesn't meet your (unspecified) requirements.  Or you could feed the signal through a filter with a very long time constant, and hence the output wouldn't be effected by quick signal changes.  But again, impossible to know from the information you've given.

Comment: Hello Phil, 

I tried to filter this signal and i didnt become that what i wanted. That i want to do, is to remove all the fast changes in my signal that occurs for maximal 2 sec. If this change that happend will stay on this value for more than 2 sec, only then it can pass to the rest of my system.

Sorry for my bad English...

I hope this explanation will helps you to understand better my problem

Answer (score 0):

[image]You can debounce your signal using sample and hold as follows:

Every time a value change is detected in the input signal, start a counter and set the output to the original (pre-changed) input value for a number of cycles that you specify. After the waiting period is over, set the output value back to the input value. If the input remains at the new value after the wait period is over, then the output will assume the new value. Otherwise it will retain the original value after the input has settled to its original value and held it for the wait duration.

This can be modeled in Simulink with a combination of 'detect change' and 'switch' blocks.

Comment: Hello Tom,

firstly thanks for your answer! Can you explain this please a little bit more? 

You said, that I have to use a counter (this is to save the previous value) a change detector and at last a switch block. But I didnt understand, how I have to combine this all together...

Comment: I added a screen capture from a SciLab model. It should be similar in MatLab.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help Tom! I will try it now in matlab Simulink! Have a nice day!